# how to: if the player touched anywhere but the buttons on the screen in a specific arrangement, he will lose a life. - Corona sdk

Tags: lua, touch, coronasdk, touch-event

I am trying to make a game using corona SDK.

The game is about 3 buttons, the player needs to press them in a specific arrangement (1==>2==>3). and if the player touched anywhere but the buttons in that arrangement, he will lose a life.

my problem is in the 2nd part. how can i do that.
any suggestions please.

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (not tested)

```
numberOfTouch = 0
match = {1, 2, 3}

...

button1.id = 1
button2.id = 2
button3.id = 3

...

local function mylistener(event)
    local phase = event.phase
    local target = event.target

    numberOfTouch = numberOfTouch + 1

    if phase == "began" then
        if match[numberOfTouch] == target.id then
            if #match == numberOfTouch then
                -- You win
            end
        else
            -- You lose
        end
    end

    return true -- to stop propagate event to more objects
end

...

button1:addEventListener("touch", mylistener)
button2:addEventListener("touch", mylistener)
button3:addEventListener("touch", mylistener)
```